# Search Formをデータベースに接続して、データをリターンする

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

データはSearchした時だけ表示出して欲しいんですが、今の場合はSearchしなくてもデータをページで見えます。この問題をどうやって解決できるか、混乱しています。

Routeのコードは

```
Route::get("/", "PagesController@welcome");

Route::post("/", "PagesController@search")->name('search.route');
```

Controllerのコードは

```
public function welcome()
{

    $estates = Estates::orderBy('price')->get(); 

    $data['estates'] = $estates; 
    return view('welcome', $data);

}

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;
    if ($q != " "){

        $estates = \DB::table('estates')->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->get();

        dd($estates);

        if(count($estates) > 0){
            return view("welcome", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
        }

    }

    return view("welcome")->withMessage("No Found!");
}
```

それでViewページは

```
<form action="{{URL::to('welcome')}}" method="post" role="search" class="searchbox">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="q" class="search" placeholder="町, 地域, 会社名, 物件名">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="search">
  </form>
  @if(isset($details))
      <p> here is the results <b>{{$query}}</b> are : </p>
    @endif
<table cellspacing='0'>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>会社名</th>
    <th>物件名</th>
    <th>住所</th>
    <th>販売価格</th>
    <th>専有面積</th>
    <th>間取り</th>
    <th>竣工時期</th>
    <th>入居時期</th>
  </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($estates as $estate)
    <tr class="even">
      <td>{{$estate->company_name}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{json_decode($estate->link)}}" target="_blank">{{$estate->name}}</a><br/></td>
      <td>{{$estate->address}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->price}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->extend}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->rooms}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->old}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->entery}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

ここで何を間違っていますが、分かりません。Any ideaはよろしくお願います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravelは経験がないのですが、コードの雰囲気的に以下のように修正すれば行ける気がします。
hereの部分を以下のように書き換えてみたらどうでしょうか？

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;
    if ($q !== null && trim($q) !== ""){//here

        $estates = \DB::table('estates')->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->get();

        dd($estates);

        if(count($estates) > 0){
            return view("welcome", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
        }

    }

    $estates = array();//here
    return view("welcome", compact('estates'))->withMessage("No Found!");//here
}
```

■追記
get時はestatesに空の配列を指定することで、空のデータを表示するようになると思います。

```
public function welcome()
{

    $estates = array();//here 

    $data['estates'] = $estates; 
    return view('welcome', $data);
}
```

Comment: 返事はありがとうございます。コードを試して見たんですが、Searchしたらこういうエラーが発生しました。`Undefined variable: estates (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)`

Comment: 2か所ほど修正を追加しました。これでどうでしょう？

Comment: はい、私の間違いです。DDを消したらちゃんとリターンができます。でもまだ全てのデータベースはSearchをせずページにあります。それをどうやってなくす事ができますか

Comment: このような感じでどうでしょうか？上のif文が変わっています。

Comment: 実際には上のコードでは問題がありません。問題なのは私は書いた、WelcomeのFunctionだと思います。それでデータベースはページで表示していますが、Searchしなくても表示です。それをどうやって解決できますか

Comment: 追記部分の修正をしていただければたぶん目的通りになると思います。

Comment: 問題解決です。本当に助かりました、ありがとうございます。